# How can I start a setInterval once the first one is cleared?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I start a `setInterval` once the previous one is done?

I have the following code:

```js
const interval = setInterval(function () {
  prePost();
  array = images;
  main(current);
  if (current < array.length - 1) {
    current++
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}(), 6200);

const interval2 = setInterval(function () {
  prePost();
  array = objects;
  main(current);
  if (current < array.length - 1) {
    current++
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval2)
  }
}(), 6200);
```

And I want `interval2` to be executed but not until `interval` is cleared and even a third one. How can this be achieved? Right now they are both executed simultaneously.

Comment: start it where you do clearInterval - or you could do `const start2 = () => { const interval2 = ...rest of that code ... };` and then just call `start2()` after `clearInterval(interval)` ...

Comment: Seeing as you have a lot of duplicate code it would be best to extract your code for starting an interval into a function if you would then make it return a Promise that resolves when you call the clear interval. you could use this to chain any amount of intervals one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Define `setInterval` for `interval2` right after `clearInterval` for the first `interval` variable and this will be called after clearing the first interval.

```js
let interval2 = null;
const interval = setInterval(function () {
  prePost();
  array = images;
  main(current);
  if (current < array.length - 1) {
    current++
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);

    interval2 = setInterval(function () {
      prePost();
      array = objects;
      main(current);
      if (current < array.length - 1) {
        current++
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval2)
      }
    }(), 6200);
  }
}(), 6200);
```

Comment: i have tried your answer but there seems to be a problem. The array images has 5 elements and i expect the code in main() to be executed 5 times. Right now it is only executed once and then it stops. I don't see any errors in the console.

Comment: I think there is a problem on `array` value. Have you logged `array` value and `current` value on console and let me know? There is no issues on the code.

Comment: This is the array: ` var images = [
      { id: 0, img: 'resources/mentalImg/img/carretera.jpeg', text: '000' },
      { id: 1, img: 'resources/mentalImg/img/ciudad.jpg', text: '000' },
      { id: 2, img: 'resources/mentalImg/img/construccion.jpeg', text: '000' },
      { id: 3, img: 'resources/mentalImg/img/fabrica.jpg', text: '000' },
      { id: 4, img: 'resources/mentalImg/img/terreno.jpg', text: '000' },
    ];`
and current is equal to 0.